# c++ how should a core game class call constructs from other files

Tags: c++

Im trying to create the core in main , then create x Players. I would like to follow the singleton structure for the other classes that i will code but I would like to get to the root of the cause of this  error I'm receiving from the compiler. I have tried different approaches to trying to solve but I'm new to c++ so this making things extremely difficult.

These are the errors I'm receiving 
**errors**

```
./Core.h:18:39: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
          CreateNewPlayer(std::string ScreenName, int ID) {
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
./Core.h:18:55: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
          CreateNewPlayer(std::string ScreenName, int ID) {
                                                  ~~~ ^
app.cpp:10:11: error: no member named 'CreateNewPlayer' in 'Core'
  CoreObj.CreateNewPlayer("DONKEYSHARK", 1);
```

**app.cpp**

```
#include "Core.h"
#include "player.h"
int main()
{
  Core CoreObj;
  CoreObj.CreateNewPlayer("screenname", 1) PlayerOne;
  std::cout << CoreObj.GetPlayerScreenName(PlayerOne) << "\n";
  std::cout << CoreObj.GetPlayerID(PlayerOne) << "\n";


  return 0;
}
```

**Core.h**

```
include<iostream>
#include"Player.h"
#include <vector>
#ifndef Core_H
#define Core_H

class Core{
  private:

  public:

    /* The CORE is Managing all the objects so it needs to know what job in what sector its going to perform in
    the first parameter will be what sector, second task, third data*/
    Core(int x = 0, std::string y = "New"){
      /* Need to know which sector the task belongs to, Becuase this class is going to get complex Qucikly */
      switch(x){
        case 0:
          CreateNewPlayer(std::string ScreenName, int ID) {
            Player(ScreenName, ID) Player;
            return Player&;
          }
        break;
        default:
        /* log function*/
        break;
      }
    }

    int GetPlayerID(Player& Player){
      return Player.GetID();
    }

    std::string GetPlayerScreenName(Player& Player){
      return Player.GetScreenName();
    }

};

#endif /*Core_H*/
```

**Player.h**

```
    include <iostream>


    #ifndef Player_H
    #define Player_H


    class Player {
      private:
      std::string ScreenName, SignUpDate, PublicKey, PrivateKey;
      int PlayerID, CreditBalance, GlobalRank, RegionalRank, localRank;
      friend class Core Player(std::string, int);

      public:
        int TotalPlayers = 0, TotalLivePlayers = 0;

        static std::string GetScreenName();
        static int         GetID();
        Player(std::string Screenname, int ID){
          this->ScreenName = Screenname;
          this->PlayerID = ID;
          TotalPlayers++;
          TotalLivePlayers++;
        }
}
```

**player.cpp**

```
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include "PlayerKeys.h"

class Player {
  private:
      std::string ScreenName, SignUpDate, PublicKey, PrivateKey;
      int PlayerID, CreditBalance, GlobalRank, RegionalRank, localRank;
      static int TotalPlayers, TotalLivePlayers;

  public:

      static int GetTotalNumbOfPlayer(){return TotalPlayers;}
      static int GetTotalNumbOfLivePlayer(){return TotalLivePlayers;}
      int GetID(){return PlayerID;}
      std::string GetScreenName(){return ScreenName;}


      Player(){
        /* overload*/
      }
      static int GetTotalNumbOfLivePlayer(){return TotalLivePlayers;}
      static int GetTotalNumbOfPlayer(){return TotalPlayers;}
      ~Player();
}
```

**core.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Player.h"
/* core    auto Deck = GetDeck();
//  std::copy(Deck.begin(), Deck.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << "\n";*/


class Core{
  /* As a security measure when core functionality needs the daily hash values */
  public:
  std::string Core::DevlopmentTeamAccessDailyHash(){
    return "DailyHAshValueTest"
  }
  std::sting Core::SystemAccessActiveHash(){
    return "SystemHAshValueTest"
  }
  std::string Core::CurrentDateAndTime(){
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    char buffer[80];
    time (&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    strftime(buffer,sizeof(buffer),"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S",timeinfo);
    std::string str(buffer);
    return str;
  }

}
```

Comment: `CreateNewPlayer(std::string ScreenName, int ID)`  declares the function. To call it just do `CreateNewPlayer(ScreenName, ID) `

Comment: @pm100 this solved a couple errors  the only errors im getting now are `no member named CreateNewPlayer` I think this is a pinter issue as u can see in the Code im returning the object to class thats constructing it but its still throwing me an error